# Uma enumeração deve ser constante no tempo de vida da solução?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação, enums, constantes, tempo-de-vida

As linguagens modernas costumam ter um tipo de enumeração que normalmente é uma faixa de constantes relacionadas. Seus membros costumam ser constantes. Na maioria das linguagens isto é até garantido pelo compilador.

Mas constância nesse caso significa que seus valores não mudarão durante a execução da aplicação.

Além disto deve ser óbvio que nenhum programador vai mudar os valores de seus membros de uma versão para outra. Ninguém vai mudar:

```
enum Direcao { Norte = 0, Sul = 1, Leste, 2, Oeste = 3 }
```

para

```
enum Direcao { Sul = 0, Norte = 1, Leste, 2, Oeste = 3 }
```

Seria uma loucura, claro. Mas e mudar a enumeração? Adicionar membros novos? Isto quebraria a semântica dela? Tecnicamente é possível criar uma:

```
enum Acoes { Falar = 0, Cantar = 1, Gritar = 2 }
```

E depois em futura versão modificá-la para:

```
enum Acoes { Falar = 0, Cantar = 1, Gritar = 2, Sussurrar = 3, Calar = 4 }
```

- Mas deveria? Que problemas isso poderia causar?
- Se não é uma boa ideia, que solução deveria ser adotada quando se sabe que a enumeração pode "crescer"?
- E o que fazer se uma enumeração foi criada, usada extensivamente na sua aplicação e agora descobriu-se que novos membros são necessários?
- Se eu tenho uma faixa de valores que serão obtidos em tempo de execução (vindos de um XML ou DB, por exemplo), em linguagens que é possível, seria adequado/faria algum sentido criar uma enumeração de forma dinâmica (com reflexão, por exemplo)?
- Faz diferença se a enumeração é usada para tratar um conjunto de *flags*? Para ser usado com `or`:

`enum Opcoes { Nenhuma = 0, Primeira = 1, Segunda = 2, Terceira = 4, Quarta = 8 }`

Ou seja, traria problemas maiores ou menores se o programador adicionar mais tarde os membros `Quinta = 16`, `Sexta = 32`, etc.?

De uma certa forma esta última dúvida é: há exceções?

Estou falando do uso para qualquer linguagem, mas se há algo importante e diferente para alguma linguagem, estou interessado particularmente em C#.

*Bônus point:* Existe alguma linguagem que consiga garantir isto? Ou é possível garantir? Eu sei que há linguagens que só compilam um `switch` se todos os membros da enumeração usada nele forem avaliados de alguma forma. Isto ajudaria mas não resolveria o problema.

Comment: Como há quem não entende os motivos de fechamento, preciso explicar que a pergunta é essencialmente uma só. Apesar de ter claramente 5 partes, elas estão relacionadas e no fundo estão ajudando a clarificar a dúvida. Dá para responder de forma relativamente curta. E nem precisa ser respondido separadamente.

Comment: Me esclarece esse último parágrafo: garantir o que? Que a enumeração não mude de uma versão do programa pra outro? (*nonsense*, só se a implementação fosse em hardware...) Ou você se refere a outra coisa?

Comment: Foi mais uma provocação, por isto nem está na pergunta mesmo. Poderia ser uma verificação no projeto se teve antes de uma forma, não poderia mexer mais. Não seria uma garantia de fato. Apenas um indicador que aquilo não poderia ser feito. Um campo `private` é dito como garantido que não pode ser acessado externamente a uma classe. Mas na prática isto é possível. O compilador garante que não pode acessar por acidente. Seria o mesmo, uma garantia que não se cometa acidentes. Eu tenho ideias como fazer isto mas admito que não implementaria em uma linguagem. Seria muito complicado.

Comment: Entendi. De fato, garantias absolutas não existem (afinal softwares foram feitos para serem mudados - daí o "soft"), mas eu sinto falta dos programas de computador serem mais "*self-aware*". Não só "sai esse código e entra esse mais novo", mas a realização que o sistema já existia numa versão mais antiga, e uma certa introspecção da sua estrutura para ajudar a estabelecer as implicações da mudança. Até que ponto isso é viável, não sei dizer, mas não custa forçar os limites um pouco até ver aonde vai dar... :)

Comment: Sei que se sentarmos para discutir algumas ideias, ficaríamos dias sem dormir :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Constância

Enumerações são apenas constantes, mais precisamente uma faixa de constantes. Os membros devem ser constantes e a enumeração deve ser constante.

Algumas linguagens definem bem o que é uma constante, outras não, mas deveriam. O C# define uma constante como um valor que deve ser imutável para toda vida da solução. De fato a [documentação do `enum`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) diz claramente que adicionar novos membros pode ser problemático. Especialmente quando eles são usados em `switch`. O problema não é exclusivo do C#.

Existe até um motivo mais acadêmico. Pelo [princípio Open-Close](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), a entidade deve estar fechada para alteração e aberta para extensão. Então a enumeração deve estar fechada para alteração. Por outras razões ela também está fechada para extensão. Faria pouco sentido. Causa problemas de polimorfismo.

Como já foi dito, o `enum` deve ser usado para facilitar a vida do programador, para evitar número mágicos soltos. Mas se o valor muda, há casos que a semântica pode mudar junto. Ou pode trazer resultados inesperados. Não pode tratar informações que podem mudar como constantes. Informações que são apenas garantidas que não mudam durante uma execução da aplicação não deveriam ser consideradas constantes. E algumas linguagens modernas diferenciam isto (`readonly` no C# e `final` no Java). Constância é outra coisa. `enum` é constante, não é apenas de leitura. E existe um motivo prático para isto.

Se a informação não é constante, não use como se ela fosse. Existem outras formas de representar informações não constantes. Use uma lista imutável, crie uma classe com dados membros *read only*, mas não use `enum`.

## Exemplos

Dá para arriscar criar um `enum Semaforo { Verde = 0, Amarelo = 1, Vermelho = 2 }`. Dificilmente haverá outra cor mas se houver a semântica mudará e toda a aplicação terá que ser mudada. Isto é bom, forçar um mudança em algo que deve ser mudado é positivo.

Em `enum Cor { Azul = 0, Verde = 1, Vermelho = 2, Roxo = 3 }`. Pode até ser uma boa ideia mas será que nunca vai precisar adicionar um `Amarelo = 4`? Se mudar, provavelmente a semântica não será mudada. Mas problemas podem ocorrer. Este novo elemento pode deixar de ser tratado. Me parece ser mais um lista que uma enumeração. Claro, tem que analisar a situação específica.

Outro exemplo claro: `enum CreditCard { Visa = 0, MasterCard = 1 }`. A chance da aplicação aceitar outra bandeira de carão de crédito é enorme. Isto claramente é uma lista, eventualmente até mutável, e não uma enumeração.

Normalmente enumerações estão mais próximas de mecanismos do que regras de negócios, mas nem sempre.

Se deseja alterar uma enumeração em *runtime* é pior ainda. Fica claro que deveria ser uma lista mutável. Java tem o [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) que ajuda nestes casos.

A maior preocupação deve ser seu uso em `switch`s. Algumas linguagens vão até impedir a compilação sem o tratamento de todos os membros. Isto é bom, porém pode haver problemas de versionamento. Se for garantido que não vai ser usado em `switch` o problema é menor mas pode ser até pior porque nada vai reclamar.

## Então é proibido usar `enum` se ele pode mudar?

Não precisa exagerar. Tem guias de estilo de linguagens (normalmente C/C++ ou outras mais baixo nível) que permitem isto naturalmente. Aí vale entender o problema e documentar. O usuário da enumeração deve estar ciente de que ele pode ser estendido. Então **não é proibido** adicionar um novo valor na enumeração, é apenas problemático e deve ser evitado. Quando não puder evitar, deve-se documentar muito bem, **antecipadamente**, que ela **pode** ser expandida com novos membros. Só deve tomar cuidado para não usar listas claras como enumerações.

## E se eu já criei uma enumeração que era para ser fixa e agora precisa adicionar um novo membro?

Depende de onde ela é usada:

- API pública - Na maior parte dos casos a única solução correta é criar uma nova API com esta nova enumeração. A não ser que possa garantir que o resto da API não é afetada na forma como interage externamente e que a enumeração só foi usada onde o novo membro não vai causar problemas (talvez porque foi documentado como deveria ser usado e como seria errado), você não pode adicionar nada sob risco de quebrar a API.
- Pequeno sistema interno de um programador só - Convenhamos, isso dá para resolver fácil com ferramentas atuais, não é problema alterar.
- Sistema interno relativamente grande com equipe grande e variável - Aqui cabe um procedimento:

1. Crie uma nova enumeração com o novo membro.
2. Documente esta nova enumeração, documente (talvez no código, com atributo/anotação da sua obsolescência) que a antiga não pode mais ser usada.
3. Na medida do possível ache todas as ocorrências da antiga e tente trocar pela nova. Peça ajuda dos outros desenvolvedores.
4. Se for possível, procure *logar* o uso da antiga para avaliar onde mais ainda está sendo usado. E tente consertar estes casos.
5. Quando for garantido que não há mais utilização da antiga, destrua-a.

## Conclusão

Não existe nada que seja proibido. Mas tem coisas que devem ser evitadas ao máximo. E é preciso saber o que fazer quando uma regra deve ser quebrada. Mas procure apenas usar enumerações para substituir números mágicos em uma faixa bem definida.

Uma [referência de quem entende](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/223046/389) (no final).

Veja também que um `enum` é menos útil do que parece: [Qual a vantagem em usar o tipo ENUM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81801/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 11):

## TL;DR

Supondo uma enumeração utilizada para mapear domínios definidos nas regras de negócio de um sistema, ela não precisa ser constante, mas deve respeitar as regras de negócio e, se necessário, mudar juntamente com elas.

## Porque usamos enumeração

A enumeração é usada principalmente por dois motivos:

1. Facilitar a vida do desenvolvedor que não precisa consultar o manual do sistema a todo momento para lembrar quais valores um campo pode assumir e o significado desses valores.
2. Reforçar a validade das constantes em tempo de compilação. Isso evita literais espalhados pelo código que inevitavelmente podem ficar defasadas com os valores reais usados no sistema.

## Deveríamos mudar uma enumeração?

Quando usamos enumerações para mapear valores de bancos de dados, devemos garantir que eles acompanhem os valores que estão no banco de dados.

Esses valores geralmente são oriundos de um domínio definido na documentação do sistema. O cuidado de não alterá-los será do analista e não do desenvolvedor.

Se em um determinado momento o analista responsável decidir que o código `7` não mais será o equivalente a `Parcela Paga` e agora deverá ser `Parcela em Atraso`, ele deverá assumir as consequências da decisão:

1. No banco de dados (update nas tabelas, procedures, triggers, views, queries)
2. Alteração nos `Enum`s e refatoração do código impactado
3. Atualização de descrições e campos nas telas
4. Etc., etc., etc.

A vantagem de usar uma enumeração fornecida pela linguagem de programação é que se você alterar a descrição da mesma, poderá encontrar facilmente os pontos afetados porque eles passarão a não mais compilar.

Além disso, várias IDEs permitem localizar todos os pontos onde um certo valor é usado não somente pelo nome do mesmo, mas analisando a semântica do código.

## Técnicas para lidar com aumento de enumerações

### Usar polimorfismo

Enumerações substituem muito bem simples constantes. Porém, se o desenvolvedor deixar de utilizar recursos que a linguagem oferece e usar `Enum`s como se fossem constantes, recheando o código de `IF`s, o crescimento do conjunto valores será mais propenso a erros.

Em Java, por exemplo, ao invés de simplesmente agrupar `IF`s assim:

```java
if (TipoFuncionario.Celetista == functionario.getTipo()) {
  //validar celetista
} else if (TipoFuncionario.QuadroPermanente == functionario.getTipo()) {
  //validar quadro permanente
} else ....
```

Poderíamos acrescentar adicionar um parâmetro ao construtor do `Enum` para forçar o desenvolvedor a declarar um validador para cada valor adicionado.

```java
public enum TipoFuncionario {

    Celetista(new CeletistaValidator()), 
    QuadroPermanente(new QuadroPermanenteValidator()), 
    Surfista(new SurfistaValidator());

    private FuncionarioValidator validator;

    private TipoFuncionario(FuncionarioValidator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public FuncionarioValidator getValidator() {
        return validator;
    }

}
```

Então todo o lugar poderia simplesmente chamar a validação assim:

```java
funcionario.getTipo().getValidator().validate(funcionario);
```

Note que para acrescentar novos valores não é necessário alterar o código existente.

<sup>Nota: Este exemplo foi extraído de [outra resposta minha aqui no SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22204/227).</sup>

### Definir valores individuais para cada constante

A linguagem Java tem um sério problema com os `Enum`s: não é possível definir um valor para cada constante como citada na questão.

Você até pode obter um inteiro baseado na ordem da constante, mas confiar na ordem de declaração das constantes não me parece nada consistente.

Então, ao invés de fazer algo como:

```java
public enum MeuEnum { valor1, valor2, valor3}
```

Deveríamos sempre associar o valor com uma constante para mapear valores de um domínio:

```java
public enum MeuEnum {
    valor1("V1"), valor2("V2"), valor3("V3");

    String id;
    private MeuEnum(String id) { 
        this.id = id; 
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima, podemos mapear valores de domínios texto ou número, sem se preocupar com a ordem ou com o nome usado para cada elemento do `Enum`.

## Casos onde não deveríamos usar enumerações

Existe uma regrinha (*rule of thumb*) mais ou menos assim:

> Se vai mudar, parametrize!

Se um domínio está em constante mudança, talvez uma enumeração não seja a resposta mais adequada.

Provavelmente seria melhor criar uma tabela no banco de dados e permitir a configuração de algumas características de cada elemento.

Isso é muito melhor que refatorar e recompilar o código frequentemente.

## Considerações finais

Mudança é inevitável.

Se for muito frequente, uma solução mais genérica que `Enum`s pode ser recomendada.

Caso contrário, o ideal é usar uma abordagem OO de acordo com a linguagem usada para reforçar o tratamento devido de cada elemento em tempo de compilação.

E, finalmente, devemos ter em mente de que a mudança de um `Enum` geralmente é resultado de mudança nos negócios, as quais devem ser devidamente analisadas para causar o mínimo de impacto no sistema.

Alguns analistas tem o costume de *nunca* excluir um elemento de um domínio, apenas depreciá-lo e adicionar uma nova opção a ser usada em novas versões do sistema. Creio que nem sempre é possível, mas é uma boa abordagem para conseguir manter dados históricos.

Answer (score 10):

## Que problemas isto [a modificação de uma enumeração] poderia causar?

Depende de como essa enumeração é modificada. Se o objeto utiliza a enumeração para persistir dados em banco, por exemplo, adicionar novos elementos podem resultar em problema se o número inteiro relacionado ao valor, ou não for especificado, ou for modificado.

Se não for especificado, o programador pode adicionar ao meio da sequência valores novos. Do seu exemplo:

```
enum Acoes { Falar, Cantar, Gritar }
```

Especificando assim, a linguagem assume como valor padrão para `Falar` como 0, `Cantar` como 1 e `Gritar` como 2. Modificando da seguinte forma:

```
enum Acoes { Falar, Cantar, Gritar, Sussurrar, Calar }
```

Não resulta em problemas, visto que os elementos foram colocados ao final. Já esta modificação:

```
enum Acoes { Falar, Cantar, Calar, Sussurrar, Gritar }
```

Faz `Gritar` ter um novo valor implícito (4). Ao trazer os dados da base, registros que antes foram salvos como `Gritar` aparecerão como `Calar`.

## Se não é uma boa ideia, que solução deveria ser adotada quando se sabe que a enumeração pode "crescer"?

Como dito antes, de duas, uma:

- Especificar os valores de cada elemento da enumeração;
- Não alterar a ordem inicial, adicionando novos elementos apenas ao final da declaração.

## E o que fazer se uma enumeração foi criada, usada extensivamente na sua aplicação e agora descobriu-se que novos membros são necessários?

O tópico anterior já responde isso.

## Se eu tenho uma faixa de valores que serão obtidos em tempo de execução (vindos de um XML ou DB, por exemplo), em linguagens que é possível, seria adequado/faria algum sentido criar uma enumeração de forma dinâmica (com reflexão, por exemplo)?

Não. Isto é desvirtuar o sentido da enumeração, que existe para trabalhar com um conjunto de valores fixos e limitados.

Até é possível fazer isso, mas comprometeria a segurança dos dados, e consequentemente do sistema todo.

## Faz diferença se a enumeração é usada para tratar um conjunto de `flags`? Para ser usado com `or`

No código compilado e executado, tudo vira `int` ou `float`. Então, não.

Comment: +1. "Isto é desvirtuar o sentido da enumeração, que existe para trabalhar com um conjunto de valores fixos e limitados."

Answer (score 7):

> As linguagens modernas costumam ter um tipo de enumeração que normalmente é uma faixa de constantes relacionadas.

Traduzindo: Linguagens de programação derivadas de C costumam ter um tipo de enumeração que normalmente é uma faixa de constantes relacionadas.

A diferença mais notável aparece nas linguagens funcionais inspiradas em ML, como Haskell. Nelas os tipos algébricos (ADTs) podem ser usados para descrever enums constantes:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue
```

e também podem ser usados para descrever estruturas de dados com mais de um "caso". Em uma analogia a C é como se fosse uma union com uma enum embutida usada como "tag".

```
-- Uma árvore é ou uma folha contendo um inteiro
-- ou um nó interno que contem uma chave inteira e duas sub-árvores.
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Int Tree Tree
```

Para se usar ADTs, essas linguagens disponibilizam o pattern matching, que é tipo um switch que garante que os ramos são executados corretamente (não é possível extrair o "filho da direita" de dentro do ramo "folha")

```
-- Função que soma os elementos da árvore
sumTree tree =
    case tree of
        Leaf x = x
        Node x t1 t2 = x + (sumTree t1) + (sumTree t2)
```

Voltando às suas perguntas:

> Além disto deve ser óbvio que nenhum programador vai mudar os valores de seus membros de uma versão para outra.

A principal característica de uma enum é que os valores são diferentes e que podemos fazer um `switch` sobre eles. Se só nos preocuparmos com isso o valor que o compilador usa internamente não faz diferença.

> Se não é uma boa ideia, que solução deveria ser adotada quando se sabe que a enumeração pode "crescer"?

Considere um tipo de dados com vários casos (por exemplo, folha vs nó da árvore) sobre o qual queremos executar várias funções (por exemplo, inserção e busca na árvore).

Se usarmos uma implementação com ADTs/enums é fácil introduzir funções novas sem mexer nas anteriores mas para introduzir um novo caso ao tipo precisamos mexer em todos as implementações existentes para tratar o novo caso no `switch`.

Por outro lado, se usarmos uma implementação orientada a objeto fica fácil adicionar um novo caso ao tipo (crie uma nova classe implementando todos os métodos existentes) mas é difícil criar uma nova função (é preciso adicionar a implementação do método em todas as classes existentes).

Em inglês essa dicotomia normalmente é conhecida como "expression problem".

> E o que fazer se uma enumeração foi criada, usada extensivamente na sua aplicação e agora descobriu-se que novos membros são necessários?

A solução mais simples é simplesmente adicionar um membro novo à enum e deixar o compilador te avisar em todos o `switch` que esquecer de tratar um dos casos. Em C e em linguagens com um `switch` parecido às vezes é difícil fazer o compilador gerar essas mensagens de forma consistente, principalmente se a enum for convertida pra `int` no meio do processo, mas em Haskell certamente isso é extremamente natural de se fazer.

> Se eu tenho uma faixa de valores que serão obtidos em tempo de execução (vindos de um XML ou DB, por exemplo), em linguagens que é possível, seria adequado/faria algum sentido criar uma enumeração de forma dinâmica (com reflexão, por exemplo)?

Acho mais sensato separar os valores internos usados pelo compilador dos valores da representação externa. Eu criaria uma funçãozinha pra converter of números no XML pra elementos na minha enum.

> Faz diferença se a enumeração é usada para tratar um conjunto de flags? Para ser usado com o ou binário.

Nesse caso você nunca vai fazer um `switch` ou `if-else` sobre um valor da enumeração. Pra mim isso é uma enum de verdade e é só uma coincidência que em `C` dá pra usar `enum`s pra definir essas flags.

Comment: Excelente complemento e até contra-ponto.