# Qual a vantagem em usar o tipo ENUM?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tipagem, enums, atributos

Quando devo usar o tipo `ENUM` porque até hoje onde vi esse tipo sendo usado ele poderia ser substituído por `VARCHAR` ou até mesmo por um simples `CHAR`, eu não consigo ver um caso onde nele realmente se faz necessário? Um exemplo prático seria útil.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Em geral, pouca. Em primeiro lugar o `ENUM` é usado como uma forma de [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101). Então usar um mecanismo semelhante pode ser útil.

Se você tem uma lista de itens dados que podem ser escolhidos exclusivamente, pode ser altamente interessante ter na sua tabela apenas um código, um ID que identifique um deles. A descrição dele pode ser mudada em algum momento, pode precisar de outras informações associadas, enfim, se você sabe fazer a normalização sabe que não deveria colocar a descrição do item, não só porque ocupa mais espaço, é uma questão de [canonicidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260464/101).

Usar esta forma é algo bom e só deve ser evitado se houver um motivo importante, se precisar do máximo da performance e souber dos riscos e o que está fazendo.

O que se questiona é usar o `ENUM` para substituir uma tabela relacionada. Em geral só tem desvantagens. Prefira o método das *lookup tables* descrito acima.

- Ler os itens do `ENUM` é um processo mais complicado do que deveria e é lento. Ele não é um dado comum.
- Alterar o `ENUM` em si exige mexer nas tabelas que o usam, entre outros problemas. É bem verdade que um `ENUM` [só deveria ser usado se você sabe que ele nunca deveria ser alterado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101).
- Não pode adicionar dados extras além da descrição.
- Não pode ser internacionalizado.
- É um elemento pertencente à tabela onde é usado, ou seja, não é um membro público da base e não pode ser reutilizado, o que praticamente mata a vantagem de canonicalização da informação.
- Não é tão simples usá-lo corretamente.

Nem falei no problema da portabilidade porque isto é algo que não parece ser problema nesta pergunta.

A vantagem é que ocupa menos espaço e obtém-se as vantagens da normalização, da separação dos detalhes do dado, mas como dito antes, tem técnicas melhores.

Obviamente não vou mostrar exemplo de uso dele. Apenas vou dizer para criar tabelas que enumeram isto. Tem duas formas de uso: ou você cria uma tabela para cada "enumeração" que precisa; ou se souber que só precisa da descrição ou outros campos de dados que serão usados em todas as enumerações, então faça uma tabela de enumeração com uma coluna extra identificando qual é a enumeração que aquela entrada se refere.

## Alternativa

Se fizer várias tabelas, essencialmente ela terá um `ID` ou código como chave primária e uma coluna com a descrição. Pode ter outras conforme a necessidade.

As tabelas consumidoras destas enumerações terão uma coluna com o `ID` para relacionar com a respectiva enumeração. Eventualmente pode colocar uma chave estrangeira para facilitar o relacionamento automático. Nem todos gostam de fazer isto. Obviamente precisará fazer `JOIN`s para pegar a descrição.

Em alguns casos pode ter só um número na tabelas consumidora e não ter a tabela com a descrição, deixar para a aplicação tratar isto. Não é o mais adequado do ponto de vista do banco de dados, mas não deixa de ser uma opção viável em muitos caso sonde se prefere deixar parte das decisões para a aplicação.

Se você usar um `VARCHAR` e descrever ali mesmo, possivelmente com um `CHECK` para limitar o que pode ser usado, está errado? Não, perde-se a normalização, tem algumas desvantagens. Mas pode ser que seja adequado para você e costuma ser mais vantajoso que o `ENUM`, pelo menos não oferece mais desvantagens que ele.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A diferença é no uso de memória... o ENUM, representa uma coleção de posições, ENUM('a', 'b','c')  = posição 1, posicao 2, posição 3, ele armazena somente um valor na posição, e não no campo, que ocuparia muito mais espaço.

Comment: Então o `Enum` é um "chamariz" para gambiarras?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Costuma ser.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, primeiro temos os requisitos de armazenamento .

**ENUM** usa **1 byte** (se estiver abaixo de 255 valores) ou 2 bytes (até o máximo de 65.535)
**TinyInt** leva **1 byte** (máximo de 255 valores)
**Boolean** é um sinônimo para **TinyInt**

Então, na superfície, eles são todos iguais. **ENUM** ocupa alguns metadados para o valor da string associado a ele.

Então, à medida que você adiciona mais valores, qualquer vantagem começa a se afastar do **ENUM**. Especialmente se você adicionar os valores após a tabela já estar em uso, porque é necessário alterar a estrutura da tabela para acomodar.

Qual é a vantagem de usar um **ENUM** ? Uma representação de sequência do que o valor significa. A importância disso depende da sua aplicação.

- Abaixo tem um link que mostra 8 razões pelo qual o uso do ENUM é ruim.

[8 razões pelas quais o uso do ENUM é ruim](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)