# Index num campo ENUM pode trazer alguma vantagem?

Tags: mysql, enums, índices

Estava lendo numa [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3049383/3096922), que os campos de uma tabela que possuem `INDEX` podem otimizar uma consulta. Claro, desde que essa consulta seja conhecida, como uma pesquisa de usuários pelo campo de `email`, por exemplo.

Tenho aqui no sistema uma tabela `Pessoa` que possui um campo `ENUM('M', 'F')` chamado **sexo**.

Essa tabela está bem "gordinha" e eu gostaria de saber se, se eu colocar um `INDEX` nesse campo, pode haver melhoria na consulta (Pois temos relatórios que fazem uma consulta específica para esses valores).

É vantajoso utilizar *index* para campos do tipo `enum` ou `boolean`  (`tinyint(1)`)?

Comment: @bigown não tem sentido com o que eu estou perguntando essa pergunta aí. Eu quero saber se posso ou não usar `INDEX` num campo `ENUM` para melhoria de performance. Na verdade, quero saber se tem alguma vantagem em relação a valores com `INDEX` como o `VARCHAR` por exemplo.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81801/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei dizer no MySQL especificamente (nem acho que importe, espero que não :P). Provavelmente não há vantagem, se for um índice com coluna única e/ou enumeração tão simples, mas não afirmo com tanta certeza.

Se for um cadastro de engenheiros pode ser que tenha algum ganho quando for buscar por mulheres. Pra que ficar procurando no banco de dados inteiro para pegar 1% das linhas? Não garanto que os resultados serão tão melhores para esse 1%, mas certamente não serão para os 99%.

Então depende do caso e tem que fazer testes com a base de dados real.

Certamente ficaria mais interessante se a coluna da enumeração/booleano fosse parte do índice composto.

Seria mais interessante se esta coluna fosse calculada a partir de outras e fosse uma auxiliar justamente para filtrar uma determinada condição complexa e facilitar certas buscas.

Alguns bancos de dados até tem [índice especial para isso mapeando os bits](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Bitmap_Indexes) e criando um índice compacto. Este índice pode ser usado em uma condição específica, em geral não é usado em uma coluna booleana. O índice é criado baseado em uma expressão `where` e o resultado é que é indexado, assim ele já consegue selecionar rapidamente as linhas que satisfazem essa condição. Isto é feito internamente e o desenvolvedor não pode criar previamente este tipo de índice.

[Pergunta com um caso que mostra que nem sempre o índice ajuda como as pessoas pensam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32052/101).

Comment: "Engenheiros" me lembrou aquela propaganda que fala das mulheres terem que conquistar o direito na política :D