# Qual o significado do termo "canônico" no contexto de programação?

Tags: terminologia

Tenho visto muito esse termo em vários lugares no que diz respeito a área de programação.

Por exemplo, já vi algo como abaixo, aqui mesmo no SOpt:

> "é necessário uma resposta canônica"

O dicionário me diz que a palavra "canônico" significa:

> Canônico é um adjetivo que caracteriza aquilo que está de acordo com
>   os cânones, com as normas estabelecidas ou convencionadas.

Mas me parece algo mais relacionado à religião. E no contexto da programação, o que isso quer dizer de fato? O que seria algo canônico e algo não-canônico na programação? Que exemplo na programação é usado o termo?

Comment: Exemplo de resposta canônica que já postei: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63736/132

Comment: O termo canônico seria algo como "*padrão de referência*".

Comment: Eu acho que sua pergunta carece de resposta canônica.

Comment: Pergunta interessante. E como falou um dos amigos, merece uma resposta canônica (rs). Na verdade, embora usada muito em meios religiosos, 'canônico' se relaciona com 'cânon'. Algo como 'geralmente aceito', 'aceito como padrão' etc. Então, uma página com FAQ é uma lista de perguntas canônicas, nesse sentido mais amplo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ca·nô·ni·co (latim canonicus, -a, -um) adjetivo
>
> 1. Do cânon ou a ele relativo.
> 2. Conforme aos cânones ou aos dogmas da Igreja.
> 3. [Linguística]  Que segue a estrutura mais usual ou mais neutra na língua (ex.: a ordem .canônica dos elementos da frase em português é
>    sujeito-verbo-.objeto).
>
> "canônica", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/can%C3%B4nica [consultado em
> 04-12-2017].

No nosso contexto pode ter alguns significados ligeiramente diferentes.

Canônico é como se fosse uma lei, é algo que diz de forma inequívoca (dentro de certos preceitos) que aquilo é verdade, preferencialmente sem ruídos que interfiram nessa verdade. É uma regra conhecida e aplicada de forma geral. Não cabe contestação (sob certos critérios, não chega ser um dogma).

Canônico é algo validado, consensual, de domínio universal, único.

Alguns sinônimos: reconhecido, autoritativo, aceito, sancionado, aprovado, estabelecido, ortodoxo.

Uma das coisas que mais podemos dizer sobre canonicidade em programação é o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). A verdade de um objeto deve estar em apenas um lugar. Não pode ter duas fontes que tratam da mesma coisa já que elas podem acabar se distanciando. Entenda que deixar algo ser modificado e/ou estendido ou composto de forma liberada como parte da arquitetura e se for bem pensado não torna algo não canônico. É conhecida como [forma canônica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form).

Em [XML tem um contexto específico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML). Ou em [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record). Ou [conteúdo web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element). Só para citar alguns.

> "é necessário uma resposta canônica"

Precisamos de uma resposta que sirva como referência universal, que seja completa e correta e diga tudo o que precisa sobre o assunto e que pode ser usada para fechar várias perguntas específicas que no fundo são respondidas bem com a resposta genérica canônica. Uma resposta responde por todas as dúvidas.

Se as pessoas entendessem cada vírgula por trás de toda filosofia canônica, separação de responsabilidades e coesão, provavelmente não falariam em OOP.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Estou pensando se não é o caso de migrar isto para o [portuguese.se].

Comment: @ÐvÐ o não canônico é exatamente o que a palavra diz, é o que não é canônico.

Comment: @ÐvÐ Na verdade o conceito é bem genérico, e a aplicação em cada área ou sub-área é diretamente derivada. Basta conhecer a área. Se for pra listar todas as aplicações de "canônico" em programação/computação, aí a pergunta já fica ampla demais.

Comment: Então a pergunta não está clara porque o termo significa isto, a não ser que quer que eu fale de tudo onde ele pode ser usada, aí é ampla.

Comment: Dei uma relida com mais calma e consegui entender o conceito. Valeu!

Comment: @bfavaretto esta pergunta está meio que no limbo entre o [pt.so] e o [portuguese.se]...