# Campo do tipo ENUM seta vazio quando não é um valor válido

Tags: mysql, enums, mariadb, constraint

### Cenário teste

Bando de dados: *10.4.11-MariaDB*

Tabela: `tabela`

Campos: `id` (`INT, PK, NOT NULL`), `ativo` (`ENUM('S','N'), NOT NULL`)

#### Instrução

```
UPDATE tabela SET ativo = 'XXX' WHERE id = 1
```

#### Retorno

> 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s):  1265 Data truncated for column 'ativo' at row 1  Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1   0.015 sec

---

### Problema

O banco de dados somente aceita o valor `S` ou `N`. Mas se eu fizer um *update* e *setar* outro qualquer, ele irá ficar vazio.

---

### Dúvidas

- Por que o banco de dados trata dessa forma? É particular deste banco de dados?
- Teria como "travar" para não aceitar valor diferente de `S` ou `N`, e caso contrário, recusar ao invés de tratar como está sendo feito?
- Que outras opções temos para campos que "tenham opções" como o `ENUM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Por que o banco de dados trata dessa forma?

Porque ele decidiu ser assim. Poderia ter adotado várias outras ações, mas o MySQL gosta de ser permissivo, é como JavaScript e outras linguagens, a preferência é fazer alguma coisa do que dar erro, mesmo que você quebre a cara.

Eu não sou totalmente contra, mas o mais correto seria dar um erro e não completar a operação. Porque se você configura que quer algo validado isso deveria acontecer, e um `enum` é uma forma de restringir certos valores.

Esse mecanismo é bastante criticado, veja: [Qual a vantagem em usar o tipo ENUM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81801/101).

> É particular deste banco de dados?

Difícil afirmar isso porque existem muitos outros. É mais fácil dizer que o padrão do SQL não manda ter esse comportamento, então foi uma escolha desse SGDB.

> Teria como "travar" para não aceitar valor diferente de S ou N, e caso contrário, recusar ao invés de tratar como está sendo feito?

Dependendo da versão do MySQL (8.0.16) há suporte ao [`CHECK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) que pode mandar verificar se está de acordo. Não sei se o MariaDB suporta.

Também pode funcionar assim:

```
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Other/EnumStrict.sql).

Não sei todas as consequências. [Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) se quiser analisar todas opções e mudar só o que é mais importante para você.

Você pode fazer o que muita gente faz quando usa o MySQL, garantir que está correto na aplicação antes de mandar para o banco de dados, o que é até mais eficiente, e costuma dar a melhor experiência de usuário, assim é irrelevante validar no banco de dados.

Quando tem uma aplicação nunca foi uma boa ideia validar no banco de ados a não ser em coisas que só ele pode fazer de forma correta. Embora há quem prefira fazer assim.

> Que outras opções temos para campos que "tenham opções" como o ENUM?

Só manuais, que parece ser o oposto do que deseja.

Comment: Então cara, que negócio besta. Qual o motivo então de usar o `ENUM()` se é preciso travar na aplicação? O que ainda não evita "erros" como houve no meu caso, de usar o ctrl+c ctrl+v e não alterar o nome do campo. Como não entra em exceção, dá a instrução como realizada, e o campo vazio. Que sem vergonhice! rs