# Uma máscara de bits pode/deve ser tipada?

Tags: design-de-linguagem

Na maioria das linguagens de programação, quando se deseja criar uma máscara de bits normalmente se usa um tipo inteiro e operações *bitwise* (and, or, xor, not, shift left, shift right...). Entretanto, embora nada impeça o programador de atribuir um valor específico (digamos, `6`: `110`) para a máscara, normalmente são criadas constantes para representar cada bit e se insiste - como boa prática, e para evitar problemas de incompatibilidade no futuro - em usar essas constantes, evitando-se os "valores mágicos". Isso não costuma ser imposto, entretanto.

Haveria algum prejuízo em se criar um tipo "máscara de bits", abstrato, cujos subtipos fossem aplicações particulares dessa técnica, e **fazer o compilador forçar o uso desse tipo**? Por exemplo, algumas linguagens que dão suporte a enumerações (*enums*) - como Java - permitem que se crie métodos cujos parâmetros têm de ser desse tipo, de modo que o programador não tem escolha a não ser usar seus membros, mesmo quando cada um deles possui um ou mais valores [únicos] associados. E uma enumeração pode ou não ser usada para implementar máscaras de bits, mas também possui outros fins[1].

Minha pergunta é, especificamente: existe algum caso de uso para máscaras de bits no qual a liberdade para usar inteiros em vez das constantes definidas traz uma vantagem significativa, e sua perda possa comprometer a expressividade do código? Creio que isso é algo que somente quem tem experiência trabalhando com máscaras de bits possa responder, mas se alguém tiver alguma referência externa tratando do assunto também seria bastante útil. Na minha experiência limitada, os principais casos de uso de uma máscara de bits são:

- Setar vários bits ou só um bit em particular (ou limpar um bit em particular);
- Verificar se um bit em particular (ou conjunto de bits) está ou não setado;
- Serializar/deserializar (i.e. salvar a estrutura de dados que contém a máscara de bit em um arquivo ou outro formato binário/textual).

Não consigo pensar em nenhum outro.

[1]: A propósito, contrário à premissa [dessa pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/215), eu tenho boas razões para querer alterar a máscara de bits ao longo da evolução dos produtos, tanto seus valores individuais quanto seu conjunto de elementos - mas sempre versionando, de modo a não quebrar código antigo. Isso restringe meu caso particular, mas não inviabiliza a pergunta (pois eu continuo interessado em saber *o que se perde* quando se usa um tipo específico pra máscara de bit em vez de um "inteiro genérico").

Comment: Se você tem um bom motivo, sabe o que está fazendo, tudo é válido... :) Espero que surjam respostas muito boas já que a pergunta é.

Comment: Eu acredito que só exista um aspecto para a necessidade de tipagem, melhorar a manutenabilidade e legibilidade do código, pois, em termos computacionais, o que importa para o processador é o valor do byte em si, não o nome da variável, etc. A vantagem/desvantagem seria apenas em termos de manutenção de código e facilidade da API. Você poderia, as vezes, valer-se de intellisense, facilitaria os testes, coisas do tipo, mas não sei se é uma grande vantagem. Se não gerar muita manutenção nessa parte, uma boa documentação supriria a necessidade de um tipo

Comment: A linguagem C# permite você combinar Enums pelo operador |. Ou seja, ela pode ser tipada. Agora se ela deve?? Não sei responder.

Comment: Esse artigo do msdn, pode te dar uma idéia dos argumentos que os engenheiros utilizaram para adicionar esse recurso à linguagem: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx#c87ff9e4-e1a8-4ab8-94e7-730db58ff2de)

Answer (score 2):

## Como funcionam:

Máscaras de bits sempre vão possuir valores com base 2, a sequencia seria basicamente: 1, 2, 4, 8... até o número máximo de bits. Imagine por exemplo se você tivesse que escolher a sua cor favorita:

```
VERMELHO = 1;
VERDE = 2;
AZUL = 4;
TODAS = 7;
```

## Valores arbitrários:

Você não pode dar qualquer valor para elas como você citou 6 ou 110. **O motivo disso é que esses valores ocupam mais de 1 bit**. Os casos que você vai ver valores assim são **combinações**, como no exemplo, **TODAS** é na verdade a combinação de todos os valores anteriores.

Esse é o uso normal de máscaras de bits e o [Windows faz muito isso nas APIs para criar janelas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx) onde você vai ver que **WS_POPUPWINDOW é na verdade a combinação** de **WS_POPUP**, **WS_BORDER** e **WS_SYSMENU**.

## Linguagens sem suporte a enumerações:

Em linguagens onde não há suporte para enums, eu costumo sim criar uma classe ou alguma série de funções que validem o valor recebido, onde vamos supor que eu use somente 4 bits, qualquer valor acima de 15 seria inválido.

## Mudar valores ao longo do desenvolvimento:

Isso pode acontecer sim mas nesse caso é bom lembrar a consequencia: **TALVEZ você terá que recompilar todos os programas que dependam das suas constantes**.

Eu digo talvez porque vai haver casos onde suas funções dependam apenas de 1 ou duas constantes que você não alterou.

## Deve ser tipada ou não?

Fica a seu critério, vamos supor que você queira adicionar constantes sem editar as antigas:

**Constantes livres (como no exemplo do Windows):** Basta declarar mais constantes que não vai quebrar código antigo.

**Subclasses (linguagens que suportam classes mas não enums):** Não precisa recompilar códigos antigos mas vai ter que criar uma subclasse toda santa vez que precisar adicionar uma constante se não quiser ter que recompilar tudo.

**Enums:** Em algumas linguages, como C#, teria que recompilar tudo que depende dela.

**Observação:** Claro que linguagens como PHP você não teria que recompilar mas ainda assim teria que atualizar todos os servidores que dependem das suas constantes, a dor de cabeça seria parecida.

Minha recomendação é: Evite máscaras de bits sempre que possível, é fácil introduzir bugs nelas e se você usar alguma metodologia como Test Driven Development vai ver que é fácil também de esquecer de escrever testes para todas as combinações delas.

Um outro problema que pode encontrar é tentar misturar elas com banco de dados, vai dificultar bastante as queries e a manutenção é [horrível](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/), aprendi da pior maneira.

## Usar constantes ou números diretos:

Algumas linguagens fazem conversão implícita entre números e as constantes utilizadas, o problema em usar números diretamente é manutenção do código, fica bem mais díficil para outro programador entender pois vai parecer que você está utilizando valores inventados mas basta comentar seu código para comunicar o objetivo.

## O que perderei por não poder utilizar números diretamente?

Converter inteiros para um grupo de constantes é extramente útil se você quiser por exemplo especificar uma configuração usando somente números e eles sejam curtos.

Um exemplo disso é alterar permissão de arquivos no linux:

```
chmod   000 ---------
chmod   400 r--------
chmod   444 r--r--r--
chmod   600 rw-------
chmod   620 -rw--w----
chmod   640 -rw-r-----
chmod   644 rw-r--r--
chmod   645 -rw-r--r-x
chmod   646 -rw-r--rw-
chmod   650 -rw-r-x---
chmod   660 -rw-rw----
chmod   661 -rw-rw---x
chmod   662 -rw-rw--w-
chmod   663 -rw-rw--wx
chmod   664 -rw-rw-r--
chmod   666 rw-rw-r--
chmod   700 rwx------
chmod   750 rwxr-x---
chmod   755 rwxr-xr-x
chmod   777 rwxrwxrwx
etc...
```

Ele trata cada número como um bitmask de 4 bits e, nesse caso, se tivesse que combinar constantes, o comando ficaria consideravelmente maior fora o fato que lembrar 3 números é até mais fácil.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas acho que você não entendeu a pergunta. Estou falando de API. No seu exemplo acima, se eu quisesse misturar verde com azul, e nada de vermelho, eu poderia usar `VERDE | AZUL` (seguindo a API) ou usar simplesmente `6` (*não seguindo* a API, trabalhando direto na sua representação interna). Isso se a linguagem me der a opção de fazer dos dois jeitos. Mas e se a linguagem não der, se ela me der só a API e mais nada, o que perco? Esse é o X da questão (essa é uma pergunta mais conceitual mesmo, sem foco numa linguagem específica nem aplicação específica).

Comment: Quanto a alterações, é claro que se eu mudar a forma de representar eu teria de recompilar tudo o que usa aquela representação. De todo modo, isso é tangencial à pergunta, citei somente para dar contexto (para mais contexto: eu não pretendo de fato *alterar* um tipo máscara de bits, mas sim criar novos tipos sem necessariamente preservar a compatibilidade com os antigos, e usar um [adaptador](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter) para que os códigos antigos funcionem na API nova).

Comment: É eu extendi o artigo além da pergunta mesmo para caso apareça alguem que nunca mecheu com bitmask ja tenha exemplos. Os últimos tópicos mostram melhor porque você deveria permitir usar números.

Comment: Sim, esse exemplo do UNIX é um argumento válido, +1. Me parece que, em se tratando de uma API extremamente popular, os "números mágicos" não são um grande problema, pois todo mundo sabe o que eles significam. Numa API mais obscura, entretanto, o benefício seria menor.

Comment: Sim mas a maioria dos casos o pessoal faz constantes, então é fácil deduzir a estrutura. Por via das duvidas sempre documente suas funções e os programadores futuros não terão dor de cabeça.