# Simplificar LINQ p => p.Tipo.ToUpper().Equals("S") && p.Modo.ToUpper().Equals("S")...,n

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Como simplificar a expressão LINQ?

```
p => p.Tipo.ToUpper().Equals("S") && p.Modo.ToUpper().Equals("S")...,n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente você vai questionar se isto é mais simples. Mas é, apesar de maior. E é o jeito mais correto, ainda que tenho dúvidas se o mais correto deva ser usado.

```
p => p.Tipo.Equals("S", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
     p.Modo.Equals("S", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)...,n
```

A não ser que tenha um contexto mais específico, não tem como fazer melhor que isto.

Se preferir o jeito "errado":

```
p => p.Tipo.ToUpper() == "S" && p.Modo.ToUpper() == "S"...,n
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/IgnoreCase.cs).

Fora isto, se a condição for sempre a mesma, dá para fazer um método auxiliar que passe por todos os membros necessários e reduzir um pouco o código, se tiver muitas condições repetidas. A lista de membros pode ser passada manualmente ou pode reduzir mais usando reflexão. Mas neste caso ficará confuso, pouco performático e se não for para fazer com todos os membros, teria que usar anotações. Ou seja, algo tão complicado que dificilmente justificaria o uso.

E aí estamos falando de fazer código reduzido e não simplificado.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que codigo mais fácil de ler e entender é também código mais simples, você poderia alterar o tipo das propriedades Tipo e Modo de string para enumerações. Assim ficaria muito mais explícita a intenção da expressão.

Exemplo - considerando que somente pelo valor 'S' não é possível saber o que significa cada propriedade, por isto defini enumerações aleatórias:

```
p => p.Tipo == Tipo.Simples && p.Modo == Modo.Serial
```

Comment: A não ser que eu não tenha entendido, não se deve fazer isto. `Enum` é para compor mecanismos e não regras de negócios: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101

Comment: @bigown - não há informação suficiente na pergunta para definir a semântica destas propriedades e, assim,  concluir o que você sugere....

Comment: Então sua resposta está errada?

Comment: Minha resposta é um exemplo, onde interpretei livremente o que poderia ser significado da string 'S' para a propriedade Tipo e para a propriedade Modo. Minha resposta tentou mostrar que é muito mais claro, *por exemplo*, definir enumerações com nomes mais explicitos dos membros para deixar clara a semântica e facilitar a leitura do código - codigo fácil de ler é também código mais simples.

Comment: Ou seja, segundo você mesmo, você respondeu o que você quis e não o que foi perguntado? Aí ela está errada, deveria ser um comentário, porque não resolve o problema real. E eu já havia notado isto.

Comment: Se vc acha assim, sinalize para os moderadores, por favor, e pare de criticar pontos de vista diferentes simplesmente pq vc não concorda com eles.