# Erro ao realizar consulta LINQ com equals na clausura where

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, operadores

Ao executar a consulta abaixo:

```
public ActionResult GridViewPartial()
    {
        if (Session["cod_cli"] != null)
        {
            int cod_cli = Convert.ToInt32(Session["cod_cli"]);

            //var model = db.DadosTecnicos;

            var model = (from s in db.DadosTecnicos
                        where s.id_cliente.Equals(cod_cli)
                        select s).ToList();

            return PartialView("~/Views/DadosTecnicos/_GridViewPartial.cshtml", model);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
```

É retornado o erro:

[image: erro]

Porém, se eu substituir o `Equals` por `==` funciona.

Mas por que?

Comment: A questão é por que está usando `Equals()`? Qual o tipo de `id_cliente`?

Comment: @bigown é tipo `int`, eu achei que a utilização de `equals` seria uma uma forma melhor de utilizar `==`

Comment: Se pode colocar na sua pergunta a tabela e a classe? @Thomas

Comment: Qual é a versão do Entity Framework!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você quer testar a igualdade de algum objeto deve usar o operador de igualdade que é o `==` que opera naquele tipo. O método `Equals()` testa a igualdade do objeto de acordo com a hierarquia. Nem sempre ele executará o que espera, a não ser que domine o funcionamento da linguagem.

Na verdade já respondi a diferença entre eles em [Qual a diferença no uso do método Equals para o operador ==?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18910/101). Tem um complemento em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111211/101). Só use o [`Equals()` com argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90851/101) que deve operar só no tipo, mesmo assim com parcimônia, entendendo se isto não terá algum efeito colateral.

Quando você usa em uma expressão LINQ que será convertida para alguma outra coisa, como o SQL, o fornecedor do acesso pode interpretar cada um deles de forma diferente. No caso o fornecedor está transformando o operador de igualdade do C# em operador de igualdade do SQL. Quando ele encontra um `Equals()` ele deve transformar em que? Este método não é necessariamente igual ao operador. Pode ser que nem opere como o tipo esperado já que ele é virtual, ele sequer sabe se dá para transformar em operador de igualdade. Talvez você saiba que dá, mas o compilador não.

O método nunca é melhor que o operador a não ser que tenha um justificativa clara e fundamentada para isso. Não deve seguir achismos. Eu já vi o AP aceitar uma resposta que ensina usar `Equals()`. Tem caso que funciona, mas é quase uma coincidência.

Isso é o que eu tenho repetido várias vezes:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas com a frase "Funcionar é diferente de estar certo"]

O certo funciona sempre, o que funciona pode só funcionar naquele caso, com aquele dado, naquela situação. Talvez o maior erro que os programadores cometem e muitos nunca aprendem é que funcionar é a pior coisa que pode acontecer para você, porque passa a sensação de dever cumprido mesmo que esteja ocorrendo o oposto.

Muitas vezes a resposta que usou `Equals()` deu certo ali, mas ensinou errado. Tem um monte de resposta aceita no site que está errada. Por isso eu confio pouco na aceitação e mais na votação, embora isso esteja cada vez mais falho também, além de sua falha inerente já que pode ser tendenciosa para a resposta que foi dada antes.