# Declaração dinâmica em propriedade de atributo

Tags: c#, genéricos, atributos, propriedade

Como parte de uma microplataforma ORM que estou desenvolvendo, eu estou definindo uma classe genérica que implementa exclusivamente *tight coupling* (1 registro x 1 objeto).

```
public class Course : MicroEntity<Course>
{
    public string fullname { get; set; }
    public string shortname { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

Para definir o comportamento desta classe, eu tenho um *Attribute* que contém todas as características de inicialização:

```
[MicroEntity(
    TableName = "mdl_course",
    IdentifierColumnName = "ID",
    IsReadOnly = true,
    UseDistributedCaching = true)]
public class Course : MicroEntity<Course>
{
    public string fullname { get; set; }
    public string shortname { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

Recentemente eu implementei um mecanismo de DatabaseAdapter para permitir conexão agnóstica a bases de dados diferentes:

```
public abstract class BaseAdapter
{
    internal abstract void CheckDatabaseEntities<T>() where T : MicroEntity<T>;
    internal abstract void SetSqlStatements<T>() where T : MicroEntity<T>;
    internal abstract void SetConnectionString<T>() where T : MicroEntity<T>;
    internal abstract void RenderSchemaMicroEntityNames<T>() where T : MicroEntity<T>;
    internal abstract BaseDynamicParameters Parameters<T>(object obj) where T : MicroEntity<T>;
    internal abstract DbConnection Connection(string connectionString);
}
```

A partir daí, declaro Adaptadores para diferentes bancos. No momento, possuo adaptadores para Oracle e MySql.

### Pergunta

Eu gostaria de poder declarar o adaptador como uma propriedade do *Attribute*:

```
[MicroEntity(
    TableName = "mdl_course",
    IdentifierColumnName = "ID",
    IsReadOnly = true,
    Adapter = new InternalAdapters.MySql.Adapter();
    UseDistributedCaching = true)]
public class Course : MicroEntity<Course>
{
    [...]
```

Porém o uso de `new()` não é permitido. Qual modelo melhor atenderia este tipo de comportamento?

Comment: Acho que depende um pouco de como vai usar o atributo. precisaria debruçar mais sobre o problema. De qualquer forma, não vejo a hora de poderem publicar essa coisa toda. Parece que vai ficar bem interessante.

Comment: @bigown seria apenas durante o construtor (uma vez inicializado não seria possível trocar o Adapter). eu também pretendo utilizar esse mecanismo para o engine de caching distribuído - por padrão Redis, mas qualquer outro Key/Value storage poderia ser utilizado. Entretanto este seria um setting global. Imagina a zona de 2 ou mais cache engines usados ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Não sei se serviria ao seu propósito mas acho que teria que usar um `enum` ou outra forma de identificar e ter algum método que trate isto para criar a instância quando necessária. Isto tem algumas dificuldades mas tem como automatizar para não ter que ficar mudando o código sempre que tiver um adaptador novo. Não é uma solução simples e perfeita, mas atende algumas necessidades. Preciso pensar em outras.

Comment: @bigown Para dizer a verdade, no momento estou usando um Enum - internamente eu tenho um switch, e dinamicamento instancio o tipo necessário. Mas minha duvida é exatamente essa, utilização de adaptadores novos sem precisar atualizar o método de construção.

Comment: Uma das soluções que penso é anotar esses tipos e com reflexão "descobrir" todos os existentes. Outro jeito é ter uma forma de "registrar" os adaptadores para este método saber onde tem que olhar. Ambos exigem que o adaptador seja escrito de um jeito que informe que ele existe. Obviamente o `enum` não atende bem isto. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101

Comment: @bigown eu tenho uma interface que serve de contrato para addons, e qualquer novo Adapter precisa implementar esta interface. Eu carrego dinamicamente todos os assemblies quando a aplicação é inicializada, e assim consigo identificar novos Adapters. Eu fiz uma implementação XGH que checa uma string literal contra uma propriedade da interface. Feio de dar dó, eu sei, mas 'funciona'.

Comment: Acho que está no caminho certo. Não deixa de ser uma forma de anotação. pensarei se acho algo melhor.

Comment: @bigown Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que atributos não aceitam inicialização dinâmica de objetos. Há duas alternativas:

## 1. Marcar o atributo com o tipo do adaptador

```
[MicroEntity(
    TableName = "mdl_course",
    IdentifierColumnName = "ID",
    IsReadOnly = true,
    Adapter = typeof(InternalAdapters.MySql.Adapter),
    UseDistributedCaching = true)]
```

## 2. Marcar o atributo com uma enumeração

```
[MicroEntity(
    TableName = "mdl_course",
    IdentifierColumnName = "ID",
    IsReadOnly = true,
    Adapter = Adapter.MySql,
    UseDistributedCaching = true)]
```

Opinativamente sou favorável ao primeiro, sobretudo porque você virtualmente não possui limites para injetar novos adaptadores na aplicação quando isto for desejado.

Ao ler o atributo, a inicialização seria bastante simples:

```
var course = new Course();
var atributoMicroEntity = course.GetType().GetAttribute<MicroEntityAttribute>();
if (atributoMicroEntity != null) 
{
    var adaptador = Activator.CreateInstance(atributoMicroEntity.Adapter);
}
```

Comment: Isso... é... perfeito! Nunca me ocorreu guardar o tipo, e ativar dinamicamente. Acabei de implementar; funcionando perfeitamente.

Answer (score 6):

Já vi esse problema ser resolvido usando um `Type` (não me lembro agora onde, mas tenho a certeza já ter visto mais que uma vez).

```
public class MicroEntityAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type Adapter { get; set; }
}

[MicroEntity(Adapter = typeof(InternalAdapters.MySql.Adapter))]
public class SomeClass {}
```

A expressão `new Class()` não é uma constante, mas `typeof(Class)` é - e, portanto, pode ser usada para inicializar um atributo.

O interpretador do atributo deverá então inicializar uma instancia do adapter usando o [`Activator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx), e lançando uma excepcão caso nao tenha um constructor público sem parametros.

Comment: Excelente solução, chegou apenas com alguns segundos depois do @Cigano. De qualquer maneira, +1 - e obrigado!