# Retornar Enum C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Tenho o seguinte enum:

```
 public enum TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00CST
 {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("00")]
    item00 = 00,
 }
```

Como faço para "pegar" o valor "00" do enum em questão ?

Já sei que normalmente se faz assim:

```
var x = (int)enumQualquer
```

Porem ele retorna "0", somente um zero, o que é de se esperar por causa do `int`.

Porem preciso do valor "00" do enum.

Como faço?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você terá que pegar o atributo `XmlEnumAttribute` do seu enumerador, então ler a propriedade Name.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public enum TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00CST
{
    [XmlEnumAttribute("00")]
    item00 = 00
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this Enum enumerador)
    {
        var membro = enumerador.GetType().GetMember(enumerador.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (membro != null)
        {
            return (T)membro.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var atributo = TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00CST.item00.GetCustomAttribute<XmlEnumAttribute>().Name;
        Console.WriteLine(atributo);
    }
}
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C0SwIS)

Comment: Obrigado. Resolvido.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que pegar o atributo que tem o texto que deseja. Pode usar isso:

```
public static class EnumExt {
    public static string GetAttributeDescription(this Enum enumValue) {
        var attributes = enumValue.GetType().GetMember(enumValue.ToString())[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlEnumAttribute), false);
        return (attributes.Length > 0) ? ((XmlEnumAttribute)attributes[0]).Name : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ydcGqZ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xteiRn). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/GetAttribute.cs).

Eu repensaria algumas coisas. [Não sei se isso é caso para usar uma enumeração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101). Enumerações não pode ficar sujeitas a mudanças de legislação ou ações que você não tem controle. Isso vai causar enormes problemas de manutenção. Tenho experiência com isso e posso afirmar que vai se arrepender de usar isso no lugar de uma tabela simples (um dicionário ou um tipo especializado. Esses dados são inerentemente mutáveis.

O nome já indica que que algo está errado. Ficou tão confuso que tem pouca utilidade. Mesmo que fosse o caso de uma enumeração, a forma usada parece estar errada. Parece que tem enumerações dentro do nome da enumeração. O recurso parece ser bem errado.

mesmo que fosse adotar essa solução precisaria fazer de uma forma que esse conteúdo seja mais significativo e fácil de organizar e manipular.

Talvez já tenha feito todo sistema pensando nisso. Ainda assim eu reformularia tudo. É um erro conceitual grave que vai trazer tantos transtornos que refazer já é a melhor solução.

Comment: Haja recompilação :)

Comment: E esse é o menor dos problemas :)

Comment: @bigown, obrigado pelas observações.