# Reflection C#, como funciona?

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão

Estou fazendo alguns testes com *reflection*, fiz esse código na base da tentativa e erro, por isso não entendi como exatamente ele funciona.

Este é o `enum` que estou usando:

```
public enum TipoDoAmbiente
{

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
    Item1,


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
    Item2,
}
```

O método `propriedade.GetValue(objeto, null);` retorna o valor do `enum`, no caso deste teste que fiz o valor é `item1`. Quando faço um *debug* e paro no `itemEnum` não aparece nada além do próprio valor.

Eu pego esse valor e passo para os próximos métodos, minha dúvida é como o resto do código "descobre" o tipo e as informações do membro se só estou passando o o valor `item1`?

```
           Type tipo = objeto.GetType();
           foreach (PropertyInfo propriedade in tipo.GetRuntimeProperties())
            {
                Type tipoBase = propriedade.PropertyType.BaseType;

                if (tipoBase.Name == "Enum")
                {
                    var itemEnum = propriedade.GetValue(objeto, null);
                    var valorEnum= (Enum)itemEnum;
                    var infoEnum = valorEnum.GetType().GetMember(propriedade.GetValue(objeto, null).ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                    var EnumAttribute = infoEnum.GetCustomAttribute<XmlEnumAttribute>().Name;

                }


            }
```

Estou testando a deserialização de um XML, e pego o objeto que foi gerado, esse objeto que é usado no código.

O que me deixou com mais duvida é que existem vários `enums` com valores iguais, exemplo `item1`.

Porem somente passando o valor `item1` para o código

```
var infoEnum = valorEnum.GetType().GetMember(propriedade.GetValue(objeto, null).ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

ele retorna a classe e a propriedade a que ele pertence.

Comment: Só só quer saber como funciona internamente? ou tem alguma dificuldade no que está fazendo? Veja se isso ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/101

Comment: Seria internamente, mas também estou aprendendo, então tenho dificuldade. Porém queria saber mesmo é como raios isso funciona, pois passei somente o valor do enum e ainda assim ele funciona. Mesmo eu criando dois enums com valores iguais, ainda assim ele "descobre" de quem ele é.

Comment: Não sei como começar responder, a pergunta está muito aberta. Eu posso responder uma coisa e ser oura que deseja. A resposta que eu mostrei ajuda de alguma forma? Tem algo mais que precisa saber? Tente deixar a pergunta um pouco mais específica. `como o resto do código "descobre" o tipo e as informações do membro se só estou passando o o valor item1?` Isso não está muito claro. O que esse exemplo de código de reflexão está fazendo aí? Tente fazer essas coisas se juntarem e fazerem sentido.

Comment: @bigown, editei a pergunta, veja se ficou menos confuso, e se for possível você me ajudar, ficarei muito agradecido. Li a resposta que você mostrou.

Comment: Vou tentar responder alguma coisa, só terminar uma coisa aqui.

Comment: Também não entendi muito bem... mesmo com essa edição.

Comment: Só como overview: o .Net possui memória gerenciada, isso quer dizer que cada coisa na memória está associada aos metadados do tipo ao qual pertence. É o gerenciador de memória que faz isso. Assim, quando é chamado `xpto.GetType()` o metadado associado é retornado para você poder consultar.

Comment: Vou tentar, mas esse código está muito solto, vai ser quase um chute. Como a pergunta não está muito clara não vai poder reclamar. Idealmente seria melhor se tivesse feito um [mcve] pra mostrar o que está tendo dificuldade de entender. Mostrar o que achou, explicar melhor o que não entendeu. A edição ajudou um pouco, mas deu mais margem ainda. Alguma coisa foi só repetição do que já tinha antes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O ideal para explicar sobre isso seria interessante um entendimento mais profundo sobre o funcionamento dos computadores, compiladores, executáveis e outros fundamentos da computação, mas vou tentar não ser técnico demais, corro o risco de ser um pouco vago.

## Metadados

O .NET foi criado para ser rico em informações para o programador. Quando o compilador cria um código ele adiciona uma série de [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101) sobre esse código. É como se fosse um banco de dados sobre o seu próprio código.

Então há uma estrutura de dados com diversas informações sobre todos os tipos de dados existentes na sua aplicação (os tipos que você criou ou os tipos das bibliotecas usadas). Essas estruturas em geral possuem textos informativos e indicativos da relação de cada dado com outros dados.

Você pode colocar informações personalizadas nesses metadados. [Tem exemplos de como eles funcionam e de informações disponíveis nos metadados em oura pergunta já feita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44900/101). Você pode até [criar seus próprios atributos personalizados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119024/101).

## Reflexão

O sistema de reflexão é um conjuntos de algoritmos para recuperar essas informações que está lá junto ao seu código. São esses métodos que está usando. Se tiver interesse em saber [mais detalhes já tem uma pergunta sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/101).

O primeiro passo é o [`GetType()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Object_GetType) que é um método disponível em todos objetos do .NET. Ele pega o objeto passado para ele, no caso do exemplo é `valorEnum`. Esse objeto tem um ponteiro para o tipo dele (simplificadamente, o jeito exato pode variar). Então no lugar desse ponteiro tem a estrutura básica do tipo e onde estão os metadados dele. Esses metadados são organizados em um objeto complexo chamado [`Type`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) (pode ver todos detalhes dele na documentação). Há uma árvore de dados sobre o tipo. São várias informações diferentes.

Uma enumeração tem alguns membros. Em algum lugar desse objeto está armazenado quais são os membros. O compilador colocou tudo que precisava lá. O método [`GetMembers()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmembers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetMembers) pega todos os membros do tipo. Todos mesmo, até alguns que não seja o que deseja. Claro que tem como filtrar isso.

Se quiser um específico desejado pode chamar o método [`GetMember()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmember?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetMember_System_String_). No caso precisa passar alguma informação que identifique esse membro. Alguma coisa em `propriedade` ajuda definir isso. Está usando o método [`GetValue()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_GetValue_System_Object_System_Object___) para obter o objeto desejado.

O retorno do `GetMember()` dará todas informações necessárias em um *array* de objetos [`MemberInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). O primeiro desses itens é o desejado e o método do LINQ `FirstOrDefault()` faz ele ser o resultado final.

## Exemplo

Eu fiz um código que pega os dados que deseja de forma simples (usei o mesmo código simples que eu passei em [resposta anterior e você não tinha gostado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153799/101), desta vez fiz passo a passo).

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tgqOmm). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xaue7t). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/EnumExample.cs).

Comment: Obrigado pela sua atenção, essa parte de metadados me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 4):

Antes de começar a te responder, é importante explicar pra que serve este código que você colocou na pergunta. [Montei um Fiddle para explicar como ele converte um objeto para XML](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JyPmXo).

Declaramos uma classe:

```
public class TesteClasse 
{
    public TipoDoAmbiente TipoDoAmbiente { get; set; }
}
```

Instanciamos a classe com um valor de `TipoDoAmbiente`:

```
var classe = new TesteClasse { TipoDoAmbiente = TipoDoAmbiente.Item2 };
```

Instanciamos tambem um [serializador XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) e um objeto especial, [`XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx), que recebe a conversão de um objeto em XML pelo serializador. Para escrever o resultado da conversão, esse `XmlWriter` precisa de um objeto de *streaming* especializado (escrita em algum tipo de memória, podendo ser memória ou disco, por exemplo). Para o exemplo, usei [`StringWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.stringwriter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TesteClasse));
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter);
```

Recapitulando:

1. Converter um objeto do C# para XML;
2. Escrever o objeto num outro objeto que formata o XML;
3. Converter o XML para uma `string` XML.

O resultado do XML é:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TesteClasse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <TipoDoAmbiente>2</TipoDoAmbiente>
</TesteClasse>
```

Repare que defini `TipoAmbiente` como `Tipo2`, mas o serializador XML escreveu apenas como `2`, conforme sua definição de atributo.

Vou fazer o inverso agora. Partir de uma `string` XML e convertê-la para o objeto, mas desta vez usando não um `XmlWriter`, mas um [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.95).aspx) e, analogamente, um [`StringReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx) ([Fiddle aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JDc1tm))

```
    var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><TesteClasse xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><TipoDoAmbiente>2</TipoDoAmbiente></TesteClasse>";
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TesteClasse));
    TesteClasse testeClasse = (TesteClasse)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)));
    Console.WriteLine(testeClasse.TipoDoAmbiente);
```

O exemplo escreverá em console `Item2`.

Agora, às suas perguntas.

> O método `propriedade.GetValue(objeto, null);` retorna o valor do *enum*, no caso deste teste que fiz o valor é `item1`. Quando faço um *debug* e paro no `itemEnum` não aparece nada além do próprio valor.
>
> Eu pego esse valor e passo para os próximos métodos, minha dúvida é como o resto do código "descobre" o tipo e as informações do membro se só estou passando o valor `item1`?

Se você quer também passar o tipo e as informações do membro, não é apenas pegando o valor dele que isso vai acontecer. Você precisa também recuperar o objeto [`PropertyInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) relacionado com a propriedade que deseja recuperar o valor. Isto você já fez aqui:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propriedade in tipo.GetRuntimeProperties()) { ... }
```

> Porem somente passando o valor `item1` para o código `var infoEnum = valorEnum.GetType().GetMember(propriedade.GetValue(objeto, null).ToString()).FirstOrDefault();`
>
> ele retorna a classe e a propriedade a que ele pertence.

Bom, isto está bem errado. Acho que o que você quer é recuperar um objeto pelo valor de `TipoDeAmbiente` dele, pelo que entendi.

Neste caso, `System.Linq` resolve melhor a situação pra você:

```
// Estou supondo que você desserializou um XML em uma lista, tipo List<TesteClasse>. 
var propertiesTipoDeAmbiente = typeof(TesteClasse).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == TipoDeAmbiente);
foreach (var propriedade in propertiesTipoDeAmbiente)
{
    foreach (var elemento in lista)
    {
        if (((TipoDeAmbiente)propriedade.GetValue(elemento, null)) == TipoDeAmbiente.Item1)
            yield return elemento; // Isto aqui acumula tudo em um IEnumerable<TesteClasse>. 
    }
}
```

## Última coisa

Isto é bem lento. [Use este pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) para ler isto com um desempenho decente.