# Por que se fala tanto em segurança em programação orientada?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, segurança

Programo em C e agora resolvi me desbravar no mundo do POO pela linguagem C#. Vejo que muitas pessoas falam de segurança e é justamente essa a minha dúvida, ao programar vejo que o próprio ambiente de desenvolvimento me limita o acesso as classes privadas assim como seus atributos e seus métodos. Quando eu defino esta classe como pública tudo o que pertence a ela fica acessível dentro de outras classes.

1° Definir como `private` uma classe protege o código do programador ou a aplicação do usuário?

2° Se eu acessar atributos e métodos de uma classe A em uma classe B eu estarei comprometendo a segurança da aplicação?

Se alguém também puder me dar umas dicas relacionadas a organização do código eu ficarei grato, pois estou acostumado com C então sempre modularizei meu código separado por 2 *headers* (funções e bibliotecas) e 1 `.c` onde chamo todas as funções. Visto que em C# possui os adventos das classes e a segurança:

3° Qual seria a melhor forma de organizar tudo em *scripts* diferentes de forma segura?

Comment: Existem muitos livros que e pessoas que falam várias coisas sem nenhum fundamento.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Segurança é uma propriedade que nada tem a ver como programação orientada a objeto. Talvez o termo fosse outro.

Definir algo como privado não protege qualquer coisa. O compilador não deixa você usar um código normal que chame aquele membro. Nada impede que o membro seja acessado por formas não normais, como [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154462/101). Inclusive não protege uma instância acessar membros privados de outra instância da mesma classe.

Essa anotação no membro é só um indicador do que não deve fazer. Isso tem a ver com encapsulamento, com ocultação de informação desnecessária ao código. Mas não entenda ocultação com proteção. É só que está dentro em um invólucro, se quiser abri-lo está tudo lá pra ver.

Acessar membros de uma classe não compromete segurança alguma. Se isso ocorresse nem daria para fazer alguma coisa.

É possível usar classes privadas, mas quase nunca elas são úteis, uma classe privada só pode ser acessada dentro de uma outra classe onde esta foi declarada.

C# pode até ser usada assim mas ela não é uma linguagem de *script*.

Fica complicado responder as outras questões, sugiro fazer perguntas mais específicas e com mais detalhes.

Sugiro também procurar uma forma estruturada para aprender esses conceitos, talvez um bom livro.

Comment: bigdown, obrigado pela resposta. Qual livro você recomendaria com base na sua experiência para eu poder entender esses conceitos que até o momento estão bastante desconexos para mim?

Comment: Não gosto de recomendar livros, mas tem uma lista em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info.