# Como funciona o modificador "file"?

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação

Em C# 11, foi introduzido o modificador de acesso `file`, que permite o uso da classe somente dentro daquele arquivo onde ela está declarada.

```
file enum Color
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}
```

Fiquei intrigado em tentar entender por trás dos panos.

- Como que este modificador fica visível no *assembly*?
- Consigo usar reflexão para instanciar ou usar membros fora do arquivo original?
- Este conceito é algo que deve ser evitado ou não?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assim como tinha a possibilidade de dizer que um tipo é `public` (visível em todo lugar da aplicação, o mais amplo), `private` (apenas visível dentro de outro tipo, o mais restrito), `internal` (visível no *assembly* que ele está contido, com alguma restrição, mas sem total controle seu), agora tem o modificador de visibilidade de um tipo chamado `file` (bastante restrito porque só pode ser usado no arquivo de código fonte onde está declarado).

Note que só vale para tipos, não pode usar em membros de um tipo ou em elementos fora de tipos.

Era uma certa falha da linguagem não ter essa restrição, porque se você precisava ter o tipo fora de outro tipo era obrigado pelo menos deixar livre para uso em todo o *assembly*. Era muito comum acabar deixando assim porque não causava grande problema, mas o mais comum era o tipo só ser necessário no arquivo onde ele estava. Em alguns casos podia colocar dentro de um tipo para ficar mais restrito, mas nem sempre isso era possível, porque era usado em mais de um tipo, e nem era tão adequado.

Obviamente ele é mutualmente exclusivo com outros modificadores de visibilidade (acessibilidade).

E claro que um nome em um arquivo pode ser usado em outro arquivo sem problemas, não há colisão de nomes. E se importar um tipo do mesmo nome o que está no arquivo tem prioridade sobre o importado.

Um detalhe importante é que o tipo só pode ser usado como herança ou outros usos indiretos em tipo com a mesma visibilidade ou menor. Imagina em um polimorfismo você usar um tipo público cuja base seja um tipo que não é público, não dá certo, né?

Obviamente que ele não pode ser importado globalmente.

Ele é contextual para não criar problemas com identificadores já existentes. Como a palavra-chave só pode ser usada em um local específico onde nunca pode ter um identificador (variável, nome de tipo, método, etc.) não cria problema de compatibilidade.

É um recurso apenas para o compilador definir se pode ou não acessar o tipo naquele momento, nada muda no código [CIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) em si ou no resultado final da aplicação.

De forma geral dá para usar pouca [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154462/101). Eu não fui a fundo, mas posso quase te garantir que haverá um [metadado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101) indicando que o tipo tem essa visibilidade, assim como já tem as outras. Ou seja, com reflexão você consegue passar por cima do que o compilador "protegeu" pra você.

O ideal é sempre usar a menor visibilidade possível, então deve usar onde for pertinente. A hierarquia é `public`, `internal`, `file`, `private`. Lembrando que o *default** é `internal`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então ele funciona como um membro `private`, mas apenas para aquele arquivo? E no IL não tem diferença dos demais sequer alguns metadados a mais?

Comment: Tem metadado, eu respondi isso.