# Enum como Object Value em DDD

Tags: c#, ddd, enums

Após muitas pesquisas na internet, me deparei com muitas opiniões divergentes...

Na minha aplicação, eu criei o `enum EstadoCivil {Casado = 1, Solteiro = 2, Divorciado = 3}`. Ele pode ser classificado como um Object Value, ou ele é simplesmente um enumerador que se relacionará com minha classe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por Object Value está querendo dizer Value Object? Se for isto uma enumeração é um [Value Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) (tem tudo o que ele precisa ter para receber esta classificação), então não tem dicotomia.

Se alguém acha que uma enumeração não é um Value Object que diga porque. Não vi nada que indique que ela não é.

[Muitas pessoas considerarão errado o uso do `enum`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101) porque esse é um mecanismo para lidar com mecanismos internos do código e não para tratar de abstrações de regras de negócios. Mas há controvérsias, por isso acha opiniões divergentes.

A faixa de valores possíveis pode mudar? Me parece que pode, mesmo que raramente. Se mudar, quer trabalhar com uma extensão disso ou remodelar a aplicação? Tem argumentos para as duas coisas. Algumas pessoas adotam por padrão poder estender a aplicação sem mexer em mais nada. Parece bom, mas na prática em vários cenários existem problemas em fazer assim.

De fato há [recomendação da própria Microsoft para uso de uma classe normal](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types.md) no lugar de uma enumeração em certos cenários (não em todos).

Fazer uma classe tende a complicar a aplicação. Mas tem casos que é necessário ou útil para resolver outras questões.

Se fizer DDD sem saber porque está fazendo, se complicar (e DDD tende complicar a aplicação) sem ter um ganho claro (e muito do que as pessoas fazem não tem um ganho claro) aí está fazendo errado, não importa o que seja. Se estiver fazendo algo que não entende totalmente (é comum as pessoas usarem coisas que acham que entendem, mas não entendem) então é a ferramenta errada.

Pra mim não é questão de ser DDD ou não, é questão de necessidade.

Adicionalmente digo que em alguns cenários há [padronização desta informação](https://www.iso20022.org/standardsrepository/public/wqt/Description/mx/dico/codesets/_Dog4YCChEeWJd9HF2tO7BA).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela informação Maniero!!!