# "enum" deve ser usado para indicar opções de regras de negócio?

Tags: java, android-studio, enums

Vou colocar um exemplo que é melhor: no supermercado tem várias categorias de produtos como hortaliças, verduras, enlatados entre outros. Para cadastrar mais `enum`s eu tenho que alterar o código ou tem como alterar dinamicamente? Se eu cadastrar apenas três no meu aplicativo vou ter que alterar o código para adicionar mais depois?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veja a diferença entre algo ser constante e algo ter a modificação proibida: [Qual é a diferença entre const e readonly?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101). É C# mas é só para entender o conceito.

Um `enum` é só uma coleção de **constantes**. Não de dados que devem ou podem ser alterados. É algo bom para mecanismos de aplicação, não para regras de negócios que costumam ser mutáveis. Eu percebo um certo abuso de enumerações para fazer isso. Tem uma [pergunta sobre isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101).

Então nem é questão de ter que alterar o código, é o mecanismo errado, que gera consequências.

Regras de negócios costumam ser melhores em coleções de dados feitas para serem expandidas ou modificadas. Por isso a categoria deveria ser um objeto como outro qualquer e deveria ter uma lista deles que pode ser facilmente alterada conforme a necessidade.

Eu usaria, se entendi bem, uma lista ou outra estrutura que atenda bem a questão com `Categoria`s nela, então tem um objeto de negócio e não um mecanismo de aplicação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Os *Tipos Enum* não foram feitos para serem adicionados/alterados/removidos de forma dinâmica. Citando a [documentação do próprio Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

> You should use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set of constants

Em outras palavras, você deve usar `enum` para representar um conjunto previsto/fixo/invariável de constantes.

Para representar algumas informações que são **imutáveis**, como os dias da semana (segunda-feira, terça-feira, etc) os *enumerators* são bem úteis. Afinal, qual a possibilidade de adicionar um novo dia da semana ao nosso calendário? :)

No seu caso, você precisa optar por manter estas categorias de forma dinâmica, fora do código compilado do seu projeto. Ou seja, fora de um `enum`. Usualmente isto é feito usando um banco de dados que, no seu caso, poderia ter uma tabela `categoria` para poder cadastrar as categorias de produto do supermercado e ler estas categorias a partir de uma consulta a esta tabela no banco de dados.

Comment: Muito obrigado. O banco de dados está pronto eu tinha duvida na utilização do enum. Ainda bem que não vai dar trabalho substituir rsrsrsrsr.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não, pois o enumerator é um tipo que pode tratar um conjunto de valores definidos, então acho que utilizar o enumerator de forma dinâmica pode não fazer sentido, no caso que vc demonstrou o certo seria usar o objeto produto, com nome do produto como atributo, então a lista de produtos poderia crescer dinamicamente.

Comment: Eu acho que é melhor esquecer o enum nesse caso pois sempre vai aparecer um tipo de produto diferente para cadastrar.

Comment: Sim, por isso utilizar uma classe Produto seria melhor.

Comment: Eu estava pensando colocar a categoria do produto como enum, mas são tantas categorias srsrsrsrs

Comment: Sim, eu entendo que tem situações como essa kk. Quando for de forma dinâmica tenta fazer como te disse acho que vai te ajudar mais.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine que o enum sirva muito bem para tamanhos de copos de café de uma cafeteria, nela existe apenas copos com tamanhos P, M e G. Nesse caso vc não quer que um usuário cadastre um copo que ele não vai conseguir vender, Um XL por exemplo.
Como o amigo respondeu acima, conjunto de constantes bem definidos.

Outro exemplo: numa aplicação para uma fazenda, os animais são separados por sexo, nesse caso não pode existir um animal que tenha um sexo diferente de macho ou fêmea.